# How does tensorflow.pad work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

There is the example of tensorflow.pad():

> ```
> # 't' =  is [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]].
> # 'paddings' is [[1, 1,], [2, 2]].
> #  rank of 't' is 2.
> ' tf.pad(t, paddings, "CONSTANT")'
> ==> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>      [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
>      [0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0],
>      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
> ```

my question is how to pad zeros in every dimention of input? And the shape of t is [2,3], why output after pad() is [4,x],how the '4' comes? 
Thanks for helping me!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is pretty clear about this. ***For each dimension D of input, paddings[D, 0] indicates how many values to add before the contents of tensor in that dimension, and paddings[D, 1] indicates how many values to add after the contents of tensor in that dimension.***

> why out put is [4, x]?

4 is the size of dimension 0, dimension 0 has padding `[1, 1]`, which according to the docs add one before the zero dimension of *t* and one after, the size of zero dimension of *t* is 2, *2 + 1 + 1*, you have 4 in the result. i.e. it padded one zero row at the beginning and ending of t respectively. Similarly for dimension 1, since *padding[1]* is *[2,2]*, two zero columns are added to *t* at the beginning and ending respectively.

Answer (score 31):

'paddings' is [[1, 1,], [2, 2]]. Try to map this vale us as [[top,bottom],[left,right]].
i.e.

```
top = 1,      //Extra padding introduce on top
bottom = 1,   //Extra padding introduce on bottom
left = 2,     //Extra padding introduce on left 
right = 2.    //Extra padding introduce on right
```

Try another example where 'padding' is [[2, 1], [2, 3]].
Output will be:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0]
 [0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Here top=2, bottom=1, left=2, right=3.